# Where is quantum physics with regards to the periodic table?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, elements

In his **Lecture's on Physics** (circa 1960's) Richard Feynman wrote that so far physics has only been able to model (solve) the hydrogen and helium atoms. So now, more than 50 year's later where are we in the periodic table? Have we progressed to heavier elements? If so what element?

And what are (were) the critical hurdles that delay this progress?

Comment: I think we have very good approximation schemes that yield numerical predictions that very nicely match many (complicated) situations, but I think Feynman may have been referring to *exact* solutions...

Comment: This sounds like an answer.

Comment: Finding better solutions to multi-electron atoms and molecules is very much an active discipline. This is no different from the many-body problem in celestial mechanics. Newton gave the solution for the two body problem in the 17th century. It took 200 years to develop powerful perturbation methods for the short term prediction of planetary movement in the solar system and numerical methods for long term stability problems analysis are still under active development, some 300 years after the most simple case was solved!

Comment: @CuriousOne , I don't agree that the mathematics of celestial mechanics applies to the mechanics of atomic structures except by gross approximation and even so only in some situations - this after reading the Lectures. Didn't the idea of the planetary structure of the atoms go away in the earlier part of the 20th century?

Comment: @docscience: Apologies if my comment could be misunderstood. I was merely trying to say that science history has seen long struggles with seemingly "easy" problems already. You are right, the physics of celestial mechanics is very different from quantum mechanics. Many dissimilar physics questions share common themes, like the importance of perturbative and numerical methods, though.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what is meant by "solving" the atom. What Feynman probably is referring to is the usual atomic Hamiltonian, which is already an approximation from the field theoretic point of view (no strong forces, etc.).

The main problem is electron-electron-interactions. If you have an atom with more than one electron, the interaction term between the electrons makes an analytic solution impossible (I guess that because this is essentially a three-body problem, you just can't give analytical solutions, but I can't give a solid reference).

Therefore, you have to do further approximations. There are many ways to do so and often, our computers are strong enough to simulate about anything we want to do, i.e. we know a good approximation to the electron structure of all the elements currently known.

A good starting point for learning about approximation schemes is Wikipedia. One of the best known methods is the Hartree-Fock approximation, which is essentially a mean field method. Starting there http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartree%E2%80%93Fock_method, at the side you'll find a whole zoo of different methods to approximate the electronic structure. They are not all about determining the structure of a single atom, but I guess at least some of them will be.

Note that for larger atoms, the usual non-relativistic quantum mechanics cannot give correct results. This is, of course, just about the electron structure. If you want to ask different questions, you might have to use different methods.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what Feynman meant. At the time I read it I just assumed the models were 'known' - for all practical purposes. Many times in the 'Lectures' Feynman relates quantum physics to results that classical physics predicts but always emphasizing that its the quantum physics that are 'correct'. In volume 1 he models the atom as a spring-mass oscillator, but that never leads to the accuracy and scope of predictions quantum mechanics has to offer. So then do we at least know Li now as well as we knew H & He back then? Be?, B? ... That will answer my question.